# How to centre text as CSS content attribute vertically and horizontally?

Tags: css

I would like to center text as CSS3 content attr vertically and horizontally. Centering should have no issues on screen resize.

Please inspect the code at: http://jsfiddle.net/epomschar/3pb3swwe/

```
    <div class="container"></div>

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'Center me!';
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/epomschar/3pb3swwe/7/

Comment: instead of giving background for `pseudo` element can you give background to the container ? it will decrease the css [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3pb3swwe/3/) i have use `:before` as a `inline-block` element which will help to `vertical align` the `inline` element  `:after`

Comment: No. It has to be as it is. Why? Because the :before and :after actually cover canvas that gets resized with javascript.  So the the two sudo elements have to be always the same size as the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `bottom: 0;` and you already got the solution.

```css
 
    
    .container {
      position: relative;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .container:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: 'Center me!';
      top: 50%;
      right: 0;
      /* bottom: 0; REMOVE THIS LINE */
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    .container:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      color: white;
      background-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a padding to `&:after`.If you want to change more, you simply add `padding-left`,`padding-right` and change the position as you want.This one `padding` attribute make changes to all over your circle,you can specify changes like what i said you before by using `padding-left` etc.

```
.container {
      position: relative;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;

      &:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: 'Center me!';
        top: 50%;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        padding:30px;   //MODIFICATION
      }

      &:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: white;
        background-color: yellow;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

      }
    }
```

Else you can add `transform: translateY(-30%);` and `margin:5%;` instead of `padding:30%;`

Comment: hmm... what about If you will need to change font size? Also the circle is responsive so the 200px can be changed as well or be set in %. Are you going to be changing the padding all the time? I don't think so. This is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: then what you can do is make all the pixels to percentages. like 30px to 30%(but you have to change according to the size of your current screen),because 30px does not equal to 30% always

Comment: Padding just doesn't work. See yourself. I need a different solution. Something like table, table-cell based. But this is not working when text comes from CSS.

Comment: actually it's working to me though,don't what is the issue with your code.just make it 20% then.

Comment: You can test your solution now. Resize your screen: http://jsfiddle.net/epomschar/3pb3swwe/4/
Is your solution still working?

Comment: Then how about changing two following components?transform: translateY(-30%); and margin:5%; instead of padding:30%; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97404/discussion-between-iroshan-vithanage-and-blix).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? The plus is right in the centre.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '+';
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 34px;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Also a solution. But the absolute position should be specified to make sure the text is centred in any scenario. But thanks.